# Get a Current year as well as list of years from 1901 to current year

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate the list of years from 1901 to 2020 as a current year, current year can change but 1901 should be same

below is the logic i am trying but there i have to mention specific number, if the current year changes to 2025 then start year will also get changes.

Below is logic i am trying to use it to extract years which is not correct for my logic

```js
const currentYear = 2030;
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({
  length: (stop - start) / step + 1
}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
console.log(range(currentYear, currentYear - 120, -1));
```

please help me with this to get years

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: okay thank you my bad @Mitya

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to ask here … if you don’t want the starting year to be the current year minus 120 – well then don’t pass _that_ as second parameter, when you call your function? Make that `1901` then, if you _always_ want that to be the starting year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with a small change, this will give you the right result:

```js
const currentYear = 2030;
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({
  length: (stop - start) / step + 1
}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
console.log("Years:",range(currentYear, 1901, -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getList = () => {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const resultArr = [];
    let year = 1901;
    while (year <= currentYear) {
        resultArr.push(year);
        ++year;
    }
    return resultArr;
}
```